# Unable to complete uploading video to cloudinary from nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudinary

I execute this code:

```
var path = __dirname + '\\videos\\example.webm';
console.log(path);
cloudinary.uploader.upload(path, { resource_type: "video" }, function(success, err) {
    console.log('suc: ' + success);
    console.log('err: ' + err)
});
```

the behaviour is that it console log correct path to 800KB .webm file

> C:\Users\Borys\Documents\igt\desktopApp\videos\example.webm

[image: img]

and then nothing happen. It doesn't console log any more info. I don't get any errors.

I'm correctly requring cloudinary classes and I'm correctly setting config (before above code)

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: 'myappname',
    api_key: 'my keys',
    api_secret: 'my keys'
});
```

Why nothing happen?

Comment: Console logs are sent to terminal where I execute my electrop application. I see `console.log(path)` there just fine and the value is correct path. Yes indeed I shoud swap success and err but it will not make it work because it doesn't matter after all if success is called err here or the other way around.

Comment: Yes `.v2.` working correctly, giving me in response object with url to video however my videos doesn't appear at cloudinary page which is weird but I dont need it, I only need URL to movie which is in response so it's OK. Post it as anwer addiotionaly u can tell me why I can't see this video at cloudinary page if u have such information or you guess something

Comment: Nevermind it refresh at cloudinary after some time. Just post it as answer so I can acept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call looks like this:

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(path, options, callback);
```

which is incorrect.

Looking [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration#upload_images_and_videos), `callback` should be the second argument, not the third. If you need to pass in additional options into that function, you must use [this](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration#quick_example_file_upload) call instead:

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(path, options, callback);
```

Notice the `v2` in the method chain.

Comment: Generally docs of this cloduinary is very very bad they give heading "upload images and videos" and show how to upload image misdirecting people and wasting time of developers.

Comment: here https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration#upload_images_and_videos